# Source code layouts in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, background in Java and Python, source code file layouts in those language are pretty standard. However I've noticed with C++ projects, there seem to be at least 3 different types of layout:

**Option 1**  All files (.hpp and .cpp) in the same directory

```
---main folder
   |
   --- file1.hpp
   --- file2.hpp
   --- code1.cpp
   --- code2.cpp
```

**Option 2**  Headers (.h .hpp) all in a single include directory and implementations (.cpp) in a src directory

```
---main folder
   |
   --- include
   |   --- file1.hpp
   |   --- file2.hpp
   |
   --- code
       --- code1.cpp
       --- code2.cpp
```

**Option 3**  Headers (.h .hpp) all in a single include directory with specific directories for different groups of headers (details, impl), all implementations (.cpp) in a single dir

```
---main folder
   |
   --- include
   |   --- file1.hpp
   |   --- file2.hpp
   |   --- directory1
   |   |    --- code1.hpp
   |   --- directory2
   |        --- code2.hpp
   |
   --- code
       --- code1.cpp
       --- code2.cpp
```

**Option 4** Similar to 3 but the implementations also have their down directories.

```
---main folder
   |
   --- include
   |   --- file1.hpp
   |   --- file2.hpp
   |   --- directory1
   |        --- code1.hpp
   |   --- directory2
   |        --- code2.hpp
   |
   --- code
   |    --- code1.cpp
   |    --- code2.cpp
   |    --- directory1
   |    |    --- code1.cpp
   |    --- directory2
   |         --- code2.cpp
```

I've had a quick read of the standard and can't seem to find any suggestions or guidance on the matter, the same goes from cppref documentation.

Is there some common layout? or is it a situation of:  *"what works for you"*

Comment: It is purely a matter of preference.

Comment: @dandan78 Not purely in practice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what things would you take into consideration when make the choice?

Comment: @JacobiJohn I generally do as mentioned in my answer. Not much point of a choice.

Answer (score 5):

It really just depends on how large the project is, and whether or not you want it used as a library. If it is a library you would definitely split the headers out. For a normal executable project I normally start off just lumping everything in one directory and running g++ to compile the lot, as the project grows and you add a makefile and what not you start adding directories to keep it tidy. In most really large projects I would expect #4. But for really small projects, #1, and that is if they even bother to split the header out of implementation.

Comment: So what I hear you're saying is that there's a sort of rule, which is a function of the code size. The smaller the project the simpler the layout, the larger the project the more specific the layout?

Comment: Basically. With a small project, there just really isn't a need for a specific layout. But with a large one being able to navigate to a file, hopefully with good logic,

Comment: So I can't edit comments and that one submitted too early. Basically, yes. With a large project being able to navigate easily to the right file is a big plus.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some common layout?

Yes. It's common to separate source and header files into their own directories. That makes it easier to deliver libraries without the source code.